# CSS selector for odd- and even-level descendants?

Tags: css, css-selectors

When looking for a CSS selector that distinguishes between **odd and even level descendants** my attempts to find it fell short. It should be scalable, it should work for any amount of nested `div`s.

In this example it means coloring the odd and even level descendants red and blue.

Is there a way to do it with CSS, or alternatively by using some other method?

```css
#parent div {
  background-color: red;
}
#parent div div {
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no direct selector for this (like `nth-*`) and there is no easy way either. You'd have to write as many descendant combinations as required (like `#parent > div`, `#parent > div > div` etc).